# typescript convert to asynchronous

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, callback

I have the following functions:

```
function f (x : number): number {
 return 1/x
}

function g (x : number): number {
 return x*x
}

function h (x : number): number {
 return f(g(x))
}
```

I am trying to convert h (g and f too if needed) to an asynchronous function just with **callbacks and not with promises** but I am stuck with that.

I know that each function should have a function callback as a parameter but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: These are inherently synchronous functions; what you you mean by converting them to async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start with `f` that provides an example of error management:

```
function f(x: number, cb: (err: any, result?: number) => void): void {
  if (x === 0)
    cb(new Error("Cannot call 'f' with zero"))
  else
    cb(null, 1/x)
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
f(5, (err, result) => {
  if (!err)
    console.log("… do something with:", result)
})
```

The `g` function is easy:

```
function g(x: number, cb: (err: any, result?: number) => void): void {
    cb(null, x * x)
}
```

And `h` becomes to look like to a good old-fashioned callback hell:

```
function h(x: number, cb: (err: any, result?: number) => void): void {
    g(x, (err, gResult) => {
        if (err)
            cb(err)
        else
            f(gResult, cb)
    })
}
```

Thanks for this moment of nostalgia.

Comment: There's nothing async about this though. It's just really awkward synchronous code :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK I assumed that the operations described in the question represented asynchronous stuff. We could write `setTimeout` but that's probably not what the author is looking for.